# Property TextHeader is not available for View

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to download a View from remote DB using Microsoft SQL Server 2016 Management Studio on Windows. I have an access to this DB, because I can preview the tables and views by running Select Top 200 rows. However, I want to download the whole view to my local disk. When I right-click on a view, and then select "Script View as" -> "Select To" -> "New Query Editor Window", select "Results to File" and click on "Execute", then I get an error:

`Property TextHeader is not available for View... The property may not exist for this object or may not be retrievable due to insufficient access rights. the text is encrypted (Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo)`

Can I resolve this issue by changing some settings or should I contact the database admin because it's the issue of access rights?

Answer (score 7):

You are most likely connecting with an account that does not have **VIEW DEFINITION** permission on that database object.

If you are not sa, you need to contact the DB admin.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/ee82df77-50da-4a95-a3ba-43aa6257f1d2/property-textheader-is-not-available-for-storedprocedure?forum=sqlsecurity

Comment: VIEW DEFINITION permission should be granted?

Comment: I was reading about some decryption scripts, but all this staff looks a bit hacky to me.

Comment: Why do you need the view on your local disk?

Comment: @TTT123 Please see a good response to the same question [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/260761/56185)